# I'm trying to copy images to a canvas. For some reason, they all start at point (0,0). What am I doing wrong? (Jython)

Tags: python

I just started a computer science class, and we're using Jython. I'm trying to get multiple pictures starting at different X and Y points, but it's just not working. My code is as follows:

```
def collage():
  setMediaPath()
  canvas=makeEmptyPicture(700, 515, white)
  chipmunks=makePicture("Chipmunks.jpg")
  chipmunksXPos=235
  chipmunksYPos=0
  copy(chipmunks, canvas, chipmunksXPos, chipmunksYPos)
  chipmunksGrayscale=makePicture("Chipmunks.jpg")
  grayscaleXPos=0
  grayscaleYPos=0
  copy(chipmunksGrayscale, canvas, grayscaleXPos, grayscaleYPos)
  chipmunksNegative=makePicture("Chipmunks.jpg")
  negativeXPos=470
  negativeYPos=0
  copy(chipmunksNegative, canvas, negativeXPos, negativeYPos)
  show(canvas)

def copy(sourcePic, targetPic, iniX, iniY):
  targetX=iniX
  for sourceX in range(iniX, getWidth(sourcePic)):
    targetY=iniY
    for sourceY in range(iniY, getHeight(sourcePic)):
      pxColor=getColor(getPixel(sourcePic, sourceX, sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(targetPic, targetX, targetY), pxColor)
      targetY+=1
    targetX+=1
```

NOTE: I am just trying to get the pictures in the right place for now. I'll be changing the original image to grayscale and negative, hence the odd names. Also, I have the media path set in the actual program, and it functions perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the copy function.

Please replace the copy function with the following code. It will copy the images side by side on to the canvas.

```
def copy(sourcePic, targetPic, iniX, iniY):
  targetX=iniX
  for sourceX in range(0, getWidth(sourcePic)):
     targetY=iniY
     for sourceY in range(0, getHeight(sourcePic)):
        pxColor=getColor(getPixel(sourcePic, sourceX, sourceY))
        setColor(getPixel(targetPic, targetX, targetY), pxColor)
        targetY+=1
     targetX+=1
```

When you are trying to figure out where your code has gone wrong you're better off breaking down it down into smaller pieces printing out results. It's a lot easier to deduce
where it's gone wrong. Just a tip for the future.